# How to access set Collection of Wrapper class in apex PageblockTable

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, set

Controller:

```
public with sharing class ControllerExtension {
   public Set<WrapperOppLineItem> shoppingCartSet {
        get;
        set;
   }

    public class WrapperOppLineItem{
        public opportunityLineItem oppLineitem {get;set;}
        public Boolean selected {get;set;}
        public Id idValue {get;set;}

        public WrapperShoppingCart(opportunityLineItem oLineItem ){
            oppLineitem = oLineItem;
            selected = false;
            idValue = oLineItem.id;
        }

        public Boolean equals(Object obj){
            if(obj!= null && obj instanceOf OpportunityLineItem){
                OpportunityLineItem li = (OpportunityLineItem) obj;
                if((li.id == idValue)){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Visualforce:

```
            <apex:pageblockTable value="{!shoppingCartSet}" var="s">
                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!s.selected}"/>                     
                    </apex:column>
            </apex:pageblockTable
```

It throws error saying that `'Unknown Property SetValue.selected'`

**Note:** 
I did not include the complete code for controller and visualforce but just the relevant part to show the problem I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the collection cannot be a `Set` in this Visualforce context. You can add a property that converts it into a `List`:

```
public List<WrapperOppLineItem> shoppingCartList {
    get {
        return new List<WrapperOppLineItem>(shoppingCartSet);
    }
}
```

and reference that `shoppingCartList` instead; that list will be referencing the same underlying `WrapperOppLineItem` objects.

You should also add a `hashCode` method to your `WrapperOppLineItem` if you haven't already. See e.g. [Using Custom Types in Map Keys and Sets](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps_keys_userdefined.htm). There is a static [System.hashCode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_system_system_hashcode) method you can use on any type object including the `Id` type, so based on your `equals`, the method would be at its simplest:

```
public Integer hashCode() {
    return System.hashCode(idValue);
}
```